# Flurry banner ad reopen after close

Tags: ios, flurry

My game need to show ADs in specificed sense,so I call Flurry's Api `displayAdForSpace` ,when exit this sense,I need to close AD banner,I called `removeAdFromSpace` ,banner disappear.but when I call `displayAdForSpace` ,AD cannot show . so anyone can help me about this , Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sending across this issue to support@flurry.com. Someone will shortly revert back on your request.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)